# Olympiad problem - last $3$ digits of $3\times7\times11\times15\times19\times23\times...\times115\times119$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, products, decimal-expansion, arithmetic-progressions

Can anyone helps me to solve this problem with full explanation or tricks pls

Find the last $3$ digits of 
$$3\times7\times11\times15\times19\times23\times...\times115\times119$$

Thanks!:)

Comment: What's the pattern? Which Olympiad? What have you tried? (do you know modular arithmetic?)

Comment: It was 5th Secondary problem of SASMO competition! I had used calculator and the answer is 125 ! But I don't know tricks to solve this problem !

Comment: And sorry sir!  I don't know what Modular Arithmetic is!!:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the last $3$ digits of a number is the remainder when the number is divided by $1000$.

Now, one can observe that the number is divisible by $125$, since it contains $15 = 5 \times 3$, $35 = 5 \times 7$, and $115 = 5 \times 23$.

Secondly, we want to find its remainder when divided by $8$. The product contains $30$ numbers, so the remainder is equivalent to $(3 \times (-1))^{15} = (-3)^{15} = (1+8)^7 \cdot (-3) \equiv -3 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$.

---

It is divisible by $125$ and leaves a remainder of $5$ when divided by $8$.

By the Chinese remainder theorem (aka trial and error), its remainder when divided by $1000$ is $\fbox{125}$.

Comment: Thanks:) but I wonder why the remainder is (3x(-1))^15

Comment: @NovemberftBlue the remainder of each element is alternatively $3$ and $7$, and $7=-1$.

Comment: I got that point !thanks. But if the remainder is 5 , why 125 is the answer . How 5 affects 125?

Comment: 000, 125, 250, 375, 500, 625, and 875 are all divisible by 125. Only 125 leaves a remainder of 5 when divided by 8. The uniqueness is because 125 and 8 are coprime and $125 \times 8 = 1000$.

Comment: Ohhh! I got it. thank you so much. It helps me a lot.:)

Answer (score 5):

One thing to notice is that there are at least 3 factors of $5$ in the product, so it is a multiple of $125.$  And it is odd, so the last three digits must be one of: $125, \; 375, \; 625, \; 875.$

Second, this product is $$\prod_{n=1}^{30} (4n-1).$$

If you multiply this out, every term has a lot of $4$'s in it, except the last two. The last term is $(-1)^{30}$.  The second last term is

$$-\sum_{n=1}^{30} 4n = -4\frac{30\cdot 29}{2} = -1740$$

which is multiple of $8$ plus $4.$ So the product must be $5$ more than a multiple of $8$.  This leaves only $125$ as the answer.

We choose to look at $125$ and $8$ because this is the prime power factorization of $1000$.

Comment: Why the product must be 5 more than a multiple of 8.?

Comment: The last term is $1$. The second last term is $4$ more than a multiple of $8$.  All the rest of the terms have at least two $4$'s in them, so they are a multiple of $8$.  So that's $1 + 4 + 0$ plus a multiple of $8$.  This is easier to express in terms of modular arithmetic.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much:)